# ffmpeg amerge ignoring channel layout

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to reconstruct a 7.1 channel output after processing, and ffmpeg keeps outputting a `5.0(side)`. (trimmed for readability)

```
ffmpeg -i "intermediate/refined.mka" -i "intermediate/extracted.data" -filter_complex "\
...
[ml9][mr9][mc2][ms1][mm2][mt2][mw2][me2]amerge=inputs=8,aformat=channel_layouts=7.1[out]" -map "[out]" "intermediate/mixed.mka"
```

Output:

```
...
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'intermediate/refined.mka':
    Stream #0:0: Audio: wavpack, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
...
Input #1, dts, from 'intermediate/extracted.data':
    Stream #1:0: Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32p (24 bit)
...
Output #0, matroska, to 'intermediate/mixed.mka':
    Stream #0:0: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
```

I am feeding 8 mono channels into `amerge` and adding the 7.1 `aformat` constraint, and it gives me a 5.0 without warning or error. By everything I've read in the docs `amerge` should only add channels, never discarding them. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AC3 doesn't support 7.1.  Only took like 25 hours of messing with the filter chain to figure it out.